# AD FS 3.0 and Users Stored in a Database

Tags: adfs, adfs3.0

Our legacy applications store user account information in a database. I can't seem to find clear information as to whether AD FS 3.0 supports authentication against both Active Directory as well as SQL Server.

To be clear about my question:

How can AD FS 3.0 be used to provide federated authentication for users stored in both SQL Server (if at all) as well as Active Directory?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, it can't.

ADFS 3.0 and below can only authenticate against AD. It can, however, use a SQL Server DB for authorization i.e. it can query the DB for attributes that it uses to build up claims.

Have a look at [Identity Server](https://github.com/IdentityServer) which authenticates against SQL Server. You can federate this with ADFS.

ADFS 4.0 (Server 2016) will be able to do this i.e. AD / LDAP for authentication.

Comment: can't find any info about ADFS 4.0 supporting SQL Server.

Comment: That's what the docs. said way back but still haven't read anything.

Comment: ADFS 4 can use a SQL attribute store the same way it worked in ADFS 2 and 3.  Works well for authorization.

Comment: Agreed. But the question was around authentication.